# How to access LibreOffice running in a Docker container from a Windows system?

Tags: docker

I am not able to deploy LibreOffice on my virtual machine using docker.

I run my container with :

```
docker run -t -d -p 127.0.0.1:9980:9980 -e "domain=<your-dot-escaped-domain>" --cap-add MKNOD libreoffice/online:master
```

That seem to run, because when I type `docker ps` my terminal return :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
d3b8849cf74c        libreoffice/online:master   "/bin/bash"         14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       127.0.0.1:9980->9980/tcp   modest_ardinghelli
```

but when I go to the URL, Firefox only show a "connection failed" message

Comment: What happens if you use `-p 9980:9980` instead of `-p 127.0.0.1:9980:9980`. Does the port 9980 listen? Could you run `netstat -nat | grep 9980`? Could you run docker without `-d` then you could see some output. Could you run `docker logs d3b8849cf74c`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Without the 127.0.0.1, the ip of the container is 0.0.0.0, how can I access it? netstat -nat | grep 9980 gives nothing.

Comment: Same thing with the logs command. The container seems to run, but I can't access it with my browser.

Comment: What happens if you try `docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:9980:9980 -e "domain=<your-dot-escaped-domain>" --cap-add MKNOD libreoffice/online:master /bin/bash`

Comment: When i do `netstat -nat | grep 9980`          `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9980          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN` But firefox show `connection reinitiate`

Comment: so the port listens

Comment: does `telnet localhost 9980` work?

Comment: `Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: Ok I will try to run it locally as well and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://hub.docker.com/r/libreoffice/online/) the container seems to be broken, i.e. multiple posts indicate that there are issues and the last one was posted two days ago. My suggestion is to look for another libreoffice docker container that works.

For example, I have created the following [dockerfile and instructions](https://github.com/030/docker-libreoffice/pull/4/files). If one builds it using:

```
docker build -t 030-libreoffice .
```

and runs the container:

```
docker run -i -t --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -u root -v \
/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro 030-libreoffice
```

LibreOffice will be started.

Comment: @BenaeSan I am looking for an alternative as well and will update the answer asap

Comment: @BenaeSan What requirements do you have regarding the libreoffice container? For what purpose do you need to use it.

Comment: It's for now only for test purpose, but we want, in my company try to use it internally, for 6 persons. Have you find why that doesn't work ?

Comment: One of the problem is that the dockerfile has not been published. I will try to create it myself.

Comment: @BenaeSan I have updated the answer. Could you follow the instructions and indicate whether LibreOffice will be started on your machine as well?

Comment: Yeah almost that seems to run, but on command launch `No protocol specified` and `Failed to open display`. Just to know, the x11 is the graphical controller ? how can I launch a new libreoffice in my browser ?

Comment: What is your Host OS?

Comment: Virtual machine => ubuntu 16.04, Host windows 10

Comment: And you run docker within the Ubuntu16.04 machine? If true why do you not run docker on Windows?

Comment: I can use dockertool on windows too, I'm just discoreving Docker in the same time as libreoffice online. So the VM is a good solution for sandboxing and just try stuff. After try with dockertool, `Failed to open display`

Comment: @BenaeSan If I run the docker container on Linux then it will work, but if it is run on Windows it fails indeed. I have created [an issue](https://github.com/030/docker-libreoffice/issues/7) and will try to solve it.

Comment: the final purpose is to deploy libreoffice online on a ubuntu server, for internally use. We want to open a new document or calc directly on a web browser. For now, on ubuntu i still have a `failed to open display`. Thanks a lot for the help